# PDF output works in macOS but not in Microsoft Windows?

Tags: pdf, boxes, output, forms, questionnaire

In the PDF the boxes can be checked individually in macOS but not in Windows. If I check one box in Windows it automatically check the boxes for the other four questions. Why?!

Output in windows below:
[image]

Code below:

```
\documentclass[pagesize=pdftex,DIV=16]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newsavebox\TBox

\begin{document}
    \begin{Form}
        \section*{Application for xxx}
        \sbox\TBox{Name: }%
        \TextField[backgroundcolor=gray!30,borderwidth=0,width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd\TBox]{
         Name: }\\[1ex]
        \sbox\TBox{Organization: }%
        \TextField[backgroundcolor=gray!30,borderwidth=0,width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd\TBox]{
         Organization: }\\[1ex]
        \sbox\TBox{Address: }%
        \TextField[backgroundcolor=gray!30,borderwidth=0,width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd\TBox]{
         Address: }\\[1ex]
        \sbox\TBox{Postal code: }%
        \TextField[backgroundcolor=gray!30,borderwidth=0,width=\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-\wd\TBox]{Postal code: }
        \sbox\TBox{Abcd: }%
        \TextField[backgroundcolor=gray!30,borderwidth=0,width=\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-\wd\TBox]{Abcd: }\\[1ex]
        \sbox\TBox{E-Mail:: }%
        \TextField[backgroundcolor=gray!30,borderwidth=0,width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd\TBox]{E-mail: }
    \end{Form} \\

    \begin{Form}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\hspace*{-0.73cm} Question \hspace*{1cm}
    \CheckBox[name=first=true,width=1em]{Ja} \hspace*{0.2cm}
    \CheckBox[name=second,width=1em]{Nej} \\\\[-0.2cm]
\hspace*{-0.73cm} Another question \hspace*{0.5cm}
    \CheckBox[name=first=true,width=1em]{Ja} \hspace*{0.2cm}
    \CheckBox[name=second,width=1em]{Nej} \\\\[-0.2cm]
\hspace*{-0.73cm} Another question \hspace*{0.5cm}
    \CheckBox[name=first=true,width=1em]{Ja} \hspace*{0.2cm}
    \CheckBox[name=second,width=1em]{Nej} \\\\[-0.2cm]
\hspace*{-0.73cm} Another question \hspace*{0.5cm}
    \CheckBox[name=first=true,width=1em]{Ja} \hspace*{0.2cm}
    \CheckBox[name=second,width=1em]{Nej} \\\\[-0.2cm]
\hspace*{-0.73cm} Last question \hspace*{0.5cm}
    \CheckBox[name=first=true,width=1em]{Ja} \hspace*{0.2cm}
    \CheckBox[name=second,width=1em]{Nej} \\\\[0.2cm]
\end{tabular}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This sounds like it could be an issue with the specific PDF viewer you’re using (e.g. Preview vs. Acrobat Reader), not just the OS.  Could you tell us which viewers you are using?

Comment: I don't have any issue when using your tags, please provide the .log file for better analyze...

Comment: Try naming the items differently. A name "first" which occurs multiple times may confuse the viewer.

Comment: Also, by the way, it is better to *minimise* the example — i.e. take out aspects that do not affect the problem.  Otherwise, everyone trying to reproduce the problem and answer the question will have to separately do this themselves, which is a lot of unnecessary repeated work.  Here I guess you can surely take out the first `Form`; and then I would try removing the styling attributes from the checkboxes, one attribute at a time, and see how far the problem persists.

Comment: This is the standard behaviour in Adobe's viewer if different items have the same name. As @TeXnician says, give them unique names. Also, avoid `=` in the names - that cannot possibly be a good thing.